# Slow DB performance after DB restore on faster server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance

We have a website running on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7, SQL Server 2008 R2 and ASP.NET. We would like to upgrade to a faster server in order to speed up our DB queries.

We have backed up our website data from our old SQL Server and have restored it on our new server. For some reason, the DB performance on the new server is much slower, compared to the old one. This is in spite of the fact, that the new server has 4 times more RAM, a 30% faster SSD and and a 2 times faster CPU compared to the old one. Both servers have the exact same version of Windows, IIS, .NET and SQL Server.

The question is how can a significantly faster server result in slower DB performance? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: have you run "update statistics" on the new server?

Answer (score 0):

Have u configured the indexes and tablespace for indexes. SQL. Server will need some time to generate indexes based on usage patterns. You can test this by running the same query a few times. It should speed up on the same requests. 
I would assume the speed was attained throughway SQL optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

Disk IO is usually the largest bottleneck in a database. Storing db files and log files on the same physical  disks will slow it down. You can also move the temp db to its own physical drive/array. run a perfmon on the  server look at average disk queue length if it is ever higher than n+1  where n its the number of physical disks then you have a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

We have found the problem... the "Power settings" on the server was set to "Balanced". We have set it to "High performance" and the DB is much quicker now

Sorry for the inconvenience